# How to setup GIMP 2.8 language in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, gimp, locale

My [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) instance runs using current locale of Windows.
But I want to run it with English.

How to do this?

I found page http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-fire-up.html#gimp-concepts-running-language , but it does not work.

(It was ok for GIMP 2.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use "quick and dirty" approach:
1) find the *\share\locale* folder and locate your current locale (for example "cs") and the english one (probably "en_GB")
2) create backup of your current one (just create a copy of the folder - like "cs_backup") and delete the content.
3) copy the content of the english locale folder to your current one (in my case I would copy content of "en_GB" folder to empty "cs" folder)

restart GIMP and you should have english locale. :-)